# How to make difference between .wxm (wxMaxima) and .c files in Linux Mint?

Tags: files, linux-mint, mime-types

I installed `wxMaxima` on my laptop a few days ago.

The issue is that files with the extension `.wxm`, that are used with `wxMaxima`, are identified as a C source files. Therefore, when I double click on such a file, it opens my text editor.

I tried right clicking on a `.wxm` file, and changing the default program — but that also changed the default program for `.c` extensions — something I don't want to happen.

The bottom line: how do I define `.wxm` extension to be of a different type than `.c` extensions?

Answer (score 5):

Important: I assume that your desktop environment or file manager runs a program based on file mime type.

Interestingly, my `file` command returned `ASCII C program text` for `.wxm` file. Definitely, this was not correct, and I have corrected this in the following way:

Suppose your home directory is `/home/user`

1. Create `/home/user/.magic` with the following contents:

   ```
   0       string  /*\ [wxMaxima\ batch\ file      wxMaxima batch file
   !:mime  text/x-wxmaxima-batch
   ```
2. Compile magic by running `file -C -m /home/user/.magic` — it will create `/home/user/.magic.mgc` file
3. Check that `file` command works as expected:

   ```
   user@host$ file wxmaxima_file.wxm
   wxmaxima_file.wxm: wxMaxima batch file
   user@host$ file -i wxmaxima_file.wxm
   wxmaxima_file.wxm: text/x-wxmaxima-batch; charset=us-ascii
   ```
4. Set up your desktop environment or file manager to run wxMaxima based on `text/x-wxmaxima-batch` mime type. (The precise way how to do this depends on such a desktop environment or file manager. So if you do not know such a details, you may ask another question.)