# How to set the Linux Mint desktop environment to use a mime type?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, mime-types

As a extension to this question: [How to make difference between .wxm (wxMaxima) and .c files in Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56582/how-to-make-difference-between-wxm-wxmaxima-and-c-files-in-linux-mint)

I'm using Linux Mint. I created a mime type. Now I want the desktop environment to use it. How do I do that?

If you need any more data, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out officla docs?

http://linuxmint.com/rel_maya_xfce_whatsnew.php

There is a soft called MIME Type Editor ...

Then, ther is this video: h t t p : / / w w w .youtube.com/watch?v=Uq8e86iY5XQ

And finally, you can always do these steps:

http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7235

I highly doubt none of these things helps ...

Comment: are you sure he is using xfce?

Comment: "I'm using Linux Mint." ... ether I am becoming too eager by depending to the way author writes this Question ... either you somehow slipped over the line ... :)

Comment: I'm not a Linux Mint user, but I am fairly sure that it comes in three flavours 1. Linux Mint (uses Mate and Cinnamon for DE) 2. Linux Mint XFCE (which uses.. well, XFCE) and 3. Linux Mint KDE (..im guessing this uses KDE). If I just hear "Linux Mint" i would suspect he is actually using the first option :)

Answer (score 0):

For Mint (and also for Ubuntu 10.04) ASSOGIATE is a useful mime-type editor.

It is no longer available in Mint 17 Qiana but I used this workaround:

1. find package candidate:
   https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=assogiate
2. add corresponding repository to `gksu synaptic` (I used Wheezy stable for Mint 17 Qiana):
   deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main
3. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install assogiate`
4. Disable repository to prevent it from changing system any further and `sudo apt-get update` again to undo update information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need double-click action, you can check [How to set an icon for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Mate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/how-to-set-an-icon-for-custom-mimetype-in-linux-mint-mate/306618). I just tried on my Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon and it works perfectly. I am after a bit more extended customization [How to show app icon in 'open with' context menu for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Cinnamon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306698/how-to-show-app-icon-in-open-with-context-menu-for-custom-mimetype-in-linux-mi) without luck yet.
But the former link serves well for mime types icons and associating applications.