# How to set an icon for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Mate?

Tags: linux-mint, icons, mime-types, xdg

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 MATE
I have a problem assigning an icon for custom (newly created) file type.

**My task:**
To set new double-click action and new icon for *.session files.

**My sequence of operations:**

```
xdg-mime install --novendor scite_session.xml
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 48 text-x-session.png text-x-session
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor scite_session.desktop
xdg-mime default scite_session.desktop text/x-session
```

No errors have been displayed during these steps.
Finally I've rebooted OS.

**My files** (used in the above steps):

*text-x-session.png*
48x48 PNG image file

*scite_session.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
   <mime-type type="text/x-session">
      <comment>SciTE session file</comment>
      <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
      <glob pattern="*.session"/>
      <icon name="text-x-session"/>
   </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

*scite_session.desktop*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=SciTE (session)
Comment=Loading SciTE session
GenericName=Text Editor
Type=Application
Exec=SciTE -loadsession:%f
Icon=Sci48M
Terminal=false
Categories=
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-session;
```

**My results:**
Everything seems to be OK except icons.

- I see proper type "text/x-session" in "properties" page of any *.session file
- Double-clicking on any *.session file invokes proper action according to "scite_session.desktop"
- But the **icon** used by caja for *.session files **is still the same** instead of my new icon.

**My question:**
How to set new icon for mimetype in Linux Mint?

I've noticed that `xdg-icon-resource` created a copy of my .png in `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes`
Probably, I should copy it manually somewhere else?

Comment: I noticed that placing these icons in local profile isn't enough. But if you place them in the same folder, where your DE stores its icons, they will work fine. Dunno where Linux Mint stores its icons, but you can discover it. Check this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/752316/123714

Comment: @whtyger - Thanks, I'll try it.  BTW, thank you for being an "excavator" (as your bronze badge tells us).

Comment: @whtyger - Thank you, it works now!  I was unaware of `gtk-update-icon-cache` and `/etc/mime.types`.

Comment: You are welcome. I spent much time to overcome this minor but annoying issue. Glad to hear that my findings can save some time of others'.

Answer (score 4):

There were necessary steps I was unaware of.

1. Add `text/x-session session` line to `/etc/mime.types`
2. Copy icon file to theme folder:

   ```
   $ sudo cp my_icon.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/mimetypes/48/text-x-session.png
   $ sudo ln -s text-x-session.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/mimetypes/48/gnome-mime-text-x-session.png
   $ sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Mint-X
   ```
3. Make icons always visible (prevent replacing icons with microtext):

   - Enter caja menu -> Edit -> Preferences -> Preview
   - Set "Show Text in Icons" to "Never".

Comment: The first step is optional. It is needed only for several applications, Apache for example. File manager displays icons of custom mimetype without this addition. Also there's no need to change `/etc/mime.types`, you can create `~/.mime.types` and add your custom types there. In the 2nd step `gnome-mime-text-x-session.png` symlink can also be omitted. Only mimetype-named icon will suffice. And the last piece of advice: add the same icons with appropriate sizes to the `32/` `24/` and `16/` folders so your custom mimetype's icons will be properly displayed in the menus and different apps.

Comment: The third step helped a lot. (i'm using nemo)