# How to show app icon in 'open with' context menu for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, mime-types

I am using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
Following "[How to set an icon for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Mate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/how-to-set-an-icon-for-custom-mimetype-in-linux-mint-mate/306618)" I successfully added icons for 3 different custom mime types <kbd>.wsa</kbd>, <kbd>.spy</kbd> and <kbd>*.stk</kbd> and associated corresponding apps to launch upon double-click. The reference link above covers that much but **I also wanted appropriate icon for the '*open with xyz apps*' context menu**. Like you see your video player icon when right clicking it for open with options:
[image]

Problem is I followed @[Egor Skriptunoff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/124598/egor-skriptunoff) and @[whtyger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/161571/whtyger) suggestion combined from the [reference post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/how-to-set-an-icon-for-custom-mimetype-in-linux-mint-mate/306618) and <kbd>.spy</kbd> mime-types shows appropriate file type icons, opens with appropriate application upon double-click and shows appropriate app icon in context menu but the other two mime-types do not show app icon in context menu whereas they show appropriate file type icons and opens with corresponding applications okay. [image]

I followed same procedures for the three mime types described in the reference post above. ***Still seeing different outcomes. What I am doing wrong and how can I get icons for the other two mime-types?***

**Procedures followed:**
**00-** (Optional?) Add `text/mime-type extension` line to `/etc/mime.types` eg. `text/stk stk`
**01-** Create *.desktop and *.xml files
**02-** Run the commands:

```
xdg-mime install --novendor ranktracker.xml 
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 32 text-stk.png text-stk
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor ranktracker.desktop 
xdg-mime default ranktracker.desktop text/stk 
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Mint-X
```

**03-** Copying appropriate icons to theme folder `/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/mimetypes/(sizes)` (all sizes `/16/22/24/32/48/96`)
**04-** Make icons always visible (prevent replacing icons with microtext):
    Enter nemo menu -> Edit -> Preferences -> Preview
    Set "Show Text in Icons" to "Never".

> Inspired from :
>   [How to set an icon for custom mimetype in Linux Mint Mate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/how-to-set-an-icon-for-custom-mimetype-in-linux-mint-mate/306618)